# Strange behavior of JMS queue in Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish, jms, openmq

My application consumes JMS messages in a Glassfish 3.1.2 server and OpenMQ as JMS provider.

The strange behavior happens when a consumer fails to process a message. In this situation Glassfish correctly move the message to the Dead Message Queue (after 2 attempts). And this is fine.

When I restart the server, the message stored in the DMQ, is sent again to the original destination (and that's ok, althoug I didn't expect this behavior). Now, also if the consumer succeed, **the message remains in the destination**.

**That's incorrect** because, after another restart of the server, the message is consumed again. Strangely this time the message is permanently removed from the queue.

The questions are:

- why the message remains in the queue?
- And why GF try to move automatically the message from the DMQ into the original one, after a restart?

Comment: Post some code; need to see how the consumer is handling exceptions, and how you are using transaction annotations.

Comment: @Raffian: it can't depend on my code because if the message is consumed without exception it disappear correctly from the queue, and when fails the message is copied correctly into the Dead Message Queue.
Anyway I am just using default CMT from a MDB and throwing a simple RuntimeException in case of error.

Comment: If you have a problem, don't make assumptions, otherwise, you might overlook the real culprit. So you're using `sendUndeliverableMsgsToDMQ`? And the value of `endpointExceptionRedeliveryAttempts` is `2`?

Comment: @Raffian: yes, failed messages are sent to the DMQ and the destination consumes a message twice before GF decides to move it into the DMQ. Anyway I am just using the default values provided by Glassfish.